# Restrict Splitview to only some Frames in Windows 10 universal app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, splitview

I followed this resource http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2015/04/implementing-hamburger-button-with.html .It worked.

But I need SplitView in only some xaml pages.How to achieve this.

Comment: What progress have you made so far?

Comment: I made splitview and its working.But the problem is it is comming in every page I made.

Answer (score 0):

When using the SplitView of this sample you actually navigate to the other pages within a frame. The Shell is a page that acts as a container for the pages of the application. 
This is done in OnInitializeAsync() 
`Window.Current.Content = new Views.Shell(this.RootFrame);` 
The final result is that all the pages of your application share the same menu that was defined in the Shell page.

You could change this by not setting the Shell as the root visual and by navigating to a page directly instead of within a frame. You should consider however if it really makes sense to restrict the menu.. Would this be a good navigation pattern for your app?